# Firebase function deployment timing out

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Today suddenly, all firebase function deployments timeout after 25 minutes, despite changing nothing about the firebase cli and other dependencies.

```
firebase-tools: 11.18.0
node: 14.20.1
firebase-admin: 11.5.0
firebase-functions: 4.2.0
```

```bash
firebase deploy --only functions:functionName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few hours later, without updating any dependencies or CLIs, the problem fixed itself. It was definetly something broken on Google side. But what's surprising is how it wasn't even listed on the status dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Although it might be for different reasons as I tried to switch from js to ts, and at the same time upgraded to from node 14 to 18 and upgraded the cli version to the latest. My bad.

Now rolled back to js but still not able to deploy. I tried to deploy the function on a staging project and it worked.